# Brightness only changes after reboot on 2020 Dell XPS 13 running KDE Neon 5.20

Tags: kde, brightness

I am running KDE Neon 5.20 on a 2020 Dell XPS 13. In `/etc/default/grub` I have `acpi_backlight=vendor` for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, because for any other setting I get nothing in `/sys/class/backlight`. However, when the kernel parameter has vendor, I have a directory called `dell_backlight`, but no `intel_backlight`. I can adjust the brightness file in the directory, then reboot to change the brightness. Is there anyway that I can make it so there is no need to reboot to change the brightness?

Already tested:

- https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness/blob/master/icc-brightness
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cannot-change-brightness-ubuntu-16-04-lts-and-onward
- https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/
- https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/10/2-ways-fix-laptop-brightness-problem-ubuntu-linux/

Output of `sudo inxi -Fz`:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 1 Distro: KDE neon 20.04 5.20 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 13 9310 v: N/A serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0DXP1F v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.0.3 date: 10/05/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 4.1 Wh condition: 50.4/51.0 Wh (99%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1185G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           Speed: 1222 MHz min/max: 400/4800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1200 2: 1201 3: 1202 4: 1202 5: 1201 
           6: 1037 7: 1201 8: 1145 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Iris Xe Graphics driver: N/A 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: fbdev,intel unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1200~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-58-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 12.61 GiB (2.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2300 NVMe 512GB size: 476.94 GiB 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 354.66 GiB used: 12.53 GiB (3.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 33.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 291 Uptime: 1d 22h 48m Memory: 15.37 GiB used: 3.02 GiB (19.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

**I'm am still new to Linux, and any help is very appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the output of "sudo inxi -Fz"
Some things to try here; https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight

The 5.6-oem kernel is what Dell/Ubuntu use on the 9310.
Because you are using an ubuntu derived OS try

```
apt-cache search linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

or
apt-cache search linux-image-oem

and install one of the answers.
If the Ubuntu packages are not available you can add a repository

```
echo "deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-bulbasaur" \
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-bulbasaur-meta.list
```

or build your own with whatever patch you find here;

[https://code.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/focal/+ref/oem](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/focal/+ref/oem)

Comment: I added the output of the inxi command to the end of the original question. I'll check out the possible solutions on the link you included.

Comment: @Ruff480 kernel 5.4 is old and XPS 9310 is new so try kernel 5.10.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what the the update to the answer means in regard to the the arch linux article. I did look through the arch linux article, however everything I saw applied to when "/sys/class/backlight" has either "intel_backlight" or "acpi_backlight" when I only have "dell_backlight".

Comment: @Ruff480 did you try the  5.10 kernel?

Comment: I have updated to the 5.10.7 kernel and it did not seem to change anything. However out of curiosity I switched to normal Ubuntu, and after a prompted update, the brightness worked. But, now that I've switched back it doesn't work again.

Comment: @Ruff480 what package did the brightness work for you on? Likely there is a patch not upstream yet.

Comment: @Ruff480 I updated the answer.

Comment: The brightness worked on the standard 20.04 LTS Ubuntu. Is that what you mean by package?

Comment: @Ruff480 so your options are: use ubuntu , or the kernel from ubuntu or build your own kernel with the patch from the Ubuntu kernel.